# Access to the path is denied. in c#

Tags: c#, windows, filestream

im programming a application with c# and now im in trouble to build and write a .txt file with this error:
`Access to the path 'E:\compex\Thursday, October 10, 2019' is denied.`
and my related code is it :

```
 private void creat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "E:\\compex\\"+DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() ;
        string msadd = filename + "\\msadd.txt";
        textpatch.Text = msadd;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filename);
        filepatch.Text =  filename;
        using(FileStream fp = File.Create(filename))
        {
            log.Text = "address file created successfully";
            Byte[] filepatchs = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(filename);
            fp.Write(filepatchs, 0, filepatchs.Length);
            log.Text = "";
            log.Text = "address  successfully";
        } 



    }
```

whats wrong with it? is there any permission in windows or code using to get that?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void creat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string filename = "E:\\compex\\"+DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() ;
        string msadd = filename + "\\msadd.txt";
        textpatch.Text = msadd;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filename);
        filepatch.Text =  filename;
        using(FileStream fp = File.Create(msadd))
        {
            log.Text = "address file created successfully";
            Byte[] filepatchs = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(filename);
            fp.Write(filepatchs, 0, filepatchs.Length);
            log.Text = "";
            log.Text = "address  successfully";
        } 



}
```

I believe, basing on your comment reply, that you meant to use `msadd` as the concatenated filename to write to in your `using` block, instead of using `filename` duplicated for both the directory and filename.